# how to use unicode beyond 0xffff in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, unicode

In a vb.net desktop application I'm currently designing, I want the user to be able to input text in a richtextbox in any kind of language, even ancient languages. So far I managed in achieving this using chrw() and a virtual keyboard of my own, but only for codes under 0xffff (65535), as chrw() doesn't take codes beyond this limit. However, there are codes beyond this limit I want to use, for ancient Greek, cuneiforms, and so on.

Does anybody know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This may be of help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf32encoding.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `String` in .NET (and in VB before that) is UTF-16 encoded.  Don't limit yourself to a single `Char`. If you take UTF-16 surrogates into account, where `String` values may require 1 or 2 `Char` values to encode a single Unicode codepoint, you will be able to handle the entire Unicode repertoire.